# Why has method=PUT been removed from a form element in HTML5?

Tags: html

Why has method=PUT been removed from a form element in HTML5?  Most RESTful implementations that I have seen use PUT to do updates on a piece of data, yet now it seems HTML5 is forcing the use of POST.

I know we can use AJAX to PUT some data, but if we can use a FORM to do the same thing, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was [removed last September](http://html5.org/tools/web-apps-tracker?from=5565&to=5566) based on [bug 10671](http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671).  That bug has since been reopened and you are welcome to comment on that bug and advocate it being reinstated.

Comment: Thanks Sam, with all of the explanations in there, it makes much more sense.  Personally, I'd like to see them put in the spec, but with some way of specifying where to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

There never was a `method="PUT"` detailed in the HTML4 spec, and it was not added to the HTML 5 spec that I know. [[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)]

Comment: Ah, I was reading the "5.1. Changes since 24 June 2010" on http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-diff-20101019/ which is labeled "HTML5 differences from HTML4" and assumed it was in HTML4, and then found out it never was.

Answer (score 1):

The PUT and DELETE methods should logically not result in a page being returned to the browser (just a status response), so it's not useful to have a form sending them.

If the server is returning a page as a response to PUT or DELETE eventhough, it's not following the principles of those methods, so it could just use a GET or a POST instead anyway.

Comment: except REST APIs are supposed to react to those methods differently. a get returns a list or single item. a post creates an item. a put updates an item. a delete removes an item. if the forms don't support the methods used to update & remove items, that's a bit of a problem.

Comment: @lo_fye: You are not supposed to use a form to call an API. That would leave the user with a blank page or a useless response instead of a page.

Comment: the form posts to your own code, which then interacts with the API. having the form specify the method to use to contact the API was convenient. Adding logic to handle that isn't a problem, it's just another step we didn't have before.

Comment: @lo_fye: I see, then you were misusing the REST interface. It's of course inconvenient that it doesn't work to do it that way any more, but not surprising that it happens sooner or later.